# Angular2 access a function/variable from another class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to access a method from parent class to child class.

My parent class is

```
 export class Parent{
     constructor() {}
     present() {
     }
 }
```

and my child class is:

```
export class Child {
    constructor() {}
    submit(){  
        this.toast.present(); 
    }
}
```

I want to call the present() method from parent class in child class.

Comment: In what sense are these parent and child classes? Does the parent know who its children are?

Comment: Have you checked [this link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qw11UOP5WxEdwRXZYfo4?p=preview)?

Comment: As per your code you want to access present() method in the parent from a method in Child. Is it? And, assuming that the ChildComponent is in ParentComponent in the view as your example?

Comment: yes @SaiyaffFarouk

Answer (score 1):

You can Emit the event using **@Output** Decorator.

your child component should be:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'child',
templateUrl: 'child.html',
})

export class Child {
@Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

constructor() {}
submit(){  
    this.notify.emit();


  }
}
```

And In parent class template:

```
<child (notify)="toast.present();"></child >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`super`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#inheritance) keyword to call a method of **Parent** from **Child**

```
class Parent{
     constructor() {}
     present() {
         console.log("I am from parent")
     }
}

class Child extends Parent{
     constructor() {
         super();
     }

    submit(){  
        super.present(); 
    }
}

let x = new Child();
x.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In **ECMA 6.0** has introduced **extends** keyword which works exactly similar to JAVA.
   This keyword is used to extend a class by creating child class which have access of all members of the parent class.
2. To access any of the member of the Parent class, we use "**super**" keyword.

   Code is attached below:

   class Parent{ 
                constructor() {

   ```
            }

            present() {

            }
        }


           class Child extends Parent {
             constructor() {
               super();
             }

             submit(){  
               super.present();   // here **super** represents an instance of Parent class
             }

           }
   ```